# Find closest element with display: block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a certain jQuery selection and I am looking to find the closest element (so self or parent) that is a block element (`display: block`).
The style is not necessarily inline, so the selector `[style*=display:block]` does not work in every case for me. I think I would need to use the computed style rather but need an efficient way to do that (if possible without a `$(this).parents().andSelf().each` loop)

Comment: use CSS class:
`.show {display: block;}` add class to element, in selector use `'.show'`

Comment: can you provide little HTML also!

Comment: `while( condition && elem.parentNode ) { elem = elem.parentNode }` and condition = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880957/detect-inline-block-type-of-a-dom-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EricG has posted in the comments [Detect inline/block type of a DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880957/detect-inline-block-type-of-a-dom-element#answer-2881008) was the answer to the question:

```
var elementStyle  =  element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element, ""); 
var displayType   =  elementStyle .display;
```