# "First Click" of Button does not hide div

Tags: javascript, html

Below code works, but the onclick only works with the function after the second click of the button. Why and what do I need to do for the button to hide the text area on the first click?

My javascript:

```
function hideShow() {                                         
   var e = document.getElementById('divHR');
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
       e.style.display = 'none';
   else
       e.style.display = 'block';

 }
```

html

```
<button id="btnHideShow" onclick="hideShow();">
  <img src="Images/arrow1.bmp" alt="Right Arrow icon" style="width:13px; 
       height:13px; border:0px;" /> 
        Hide or show Human Resources  Information 
</button>
<div id="divHR" class="showHRInfo">
  <h3 id="h3Inline">About Windsurf Human Resource (HR) division </h3>
  <p id="pWindSurfHR" > Windsurf values and respects its employees very highly.  
         Should you have any problem, questions or concerns please
         contact our Human Resource  division.  They are always at your service. 
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `console.log(e.style.display);` will answer why

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880957/detect-inline-block-type-of-a-dom-element

Comment: console.log will answer if you know where to look for logs in browsers. Install firebug on firefox and then check it using F12 key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should work,

```
 function hideShow() {                                         
       var e = document.getElementById('divHR');
       if(e.style.display != 'none')
           e.style.display = 'none';
       else
           e.style.display = 'block';

     }
```

Your div style display property might not set 'block'. If so, thus your code set block your display property.