# How do I check if an element is a flow element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-node

When I insert a `div` into a `p` element, the DOM will correct that to

```
<p></p>
<div></div>
```

Same for a `figure` element. It can't be a child of `p`. So called **flow** elements are only allowed into parents that allow flow elements.

How do I check with JavaScript if a node is a **flow** element, or an element that allows **flow** elements as children?

**Update**
This has nothing to do with CSS. This is not about style, it's about the DOM.
A `div` can have a `div` as a child, but a `p` cannot have a `p` as a child.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect inline/block type of a DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880957/detect-inline-block-type-of-a-dom-element)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn `div` and `span` are both flow elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Main_content_categories

Comment: Read documentation?

Comment: I don't think there is a build in way to do this but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's not something like that but what you can do is 
implement your method

for example that's is snapshot from p element

```
p​
 tagName: "P"
 nodeName: "P"
```

> You will find those attr if you console.log(p) which is the element
>   , so you can implement a method that go through the document and check the element or for parts you needs
>
> With specified array to decide if it's flow or not 
>   for example [p, figure, ...]
>   and check if in the array then return that is flow

Answer (score 0):

You probably can get the display style of an element to detect if the element is flow or phrasing.

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).display === 'block'
```